# Is couchdb suitable to build a wiki engine?

Tags: couchdb, wiki-engine

Each document of couchdb will have a new version after updating, and the previous one is still in the database.

I think this feature is suitable to build a wiki engine. But I'm newbie of couchdb, I'm not so sure.

What's your opinion?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main issue I see with it is that the versioning information will be lost if you compact the database. I'm not sure whether it'd be good to have an application depend on such a feature.

Comment: That's a big issue. Thank you!